# Simple JavaScript function not working on IE7, no errors on DebugBar

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I have this HTML page with a simple function triggered onclick. This is on a link that makes a menu item show sub-items. This doesn't seem to work on IE7, however, it works on IE8+

JS:

```
  function showSub(id) 
  {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
    else
       e.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><a onclick="showSub('sub')"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul id="sub">
<li><a href="solutions.html"><span>Solutions</span></a>
</li>
<li><a href="company.html"><span>Company</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul 
{
   font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
   z-index: 999 !important;
   display: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually have IE7 users? add href="#" and cancel the click events and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: IE7 makes up a whopping .4% of the user market.  MS will officially stop support of this browser on 08 April 2014.  Stop supporting IE7.

Comment: @madu When you click on your link, the event onclick work? Use an `console.log()` and `alert()` in your function to verify.

Comment: @R3tep It looks like the event does not work on IE7. It's odd though because the toggle function works on IE8, but the alerts/console.logs don't work either on it.

Comment: @epascarello Unfortunately there are still a few IE7 users in my country. I won't invest much time on this but I would like to have it working properly. href="#" responds fine

Comment: @madu Try to stop the link action like this `<a href="#" onclick="showSub('sub'); return false;">`

Comment: @R3tep I'm sorry, I miread what you said. It still doesn't work. It works on other versions though

Comment: @madu Is it possible that you test by inserting the function js directly into the html page between two script tag

Comment: @R3tep no luck with that either. Thanks for your help either way :)